# Blackscreen after plymouth on Lubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu, plymouth

**To potential close voters:** I have looked through [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but neither `nomodeset` nor `apci=off + nolapic` worked.

---

I am trying to install Lubuntu on an ancient laptop (Pentium III Mobile, 384MB RAM). While I can boot it from the install DVD just fine, after the plymouth boot screen finishes, the display simply goes black. However, I am in fact able to get into `tty1` and run commands. I attempted to run `sudo service lightdm start`, but it said that starting the job failed. I also tried `startx`, but it segfaulted.

Interestingly, if I do `sudo shutdown -h now`, the plymouth shutdown screen appears, so it seems to me that this is more of an X server issue than a video driver issue.

Any other boot parameters I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I figured it out. After I couldn't get Lubuntu to boot properly, I tried Puppy Linux. It came up with a message about `pup-xxx.sfs not found`. So I tried it on another computer, and it worked just fine. O_o. So I searched that error message on Google, and found a thread where someone said that error can occur if Puppy can't find the install medium. Then I remembered that the laptop  in question uses a Firewire DVD drive. On a hunch, I used the PLOP boot manager to boot from a USB drive instead of a DVD, and what do you know? It worked!

**TL;DR** The Linux kernel didn't like the Firewire DVD drive I guess.